# How to find out different elements in two arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have array in c#

```
int array1 = new int[]{1,2,3,3,4,5};
```

and I have two problems:

1. I do not know how delete duplicate elements in array.
2. When I compare array1 to array3 `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`, how many elements disappear and what numbers are they?

I have no idea to accomplish this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is using [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx), and in particular the methods [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) and [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx).

To remove duplicates from `array1`:

```
 var withoutDupes = array1.Distinct().ToArray();
```

To see what elements were added in `array2` using `array1` as reference:

```
 var added = array2.Except(array1).ToArray();
```

To see what elements were removed in `array2` using `array1` as reference:

```
 var removed = array1.Except(array2).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'd add that the `ToArray` is only necessary if you actually need the array for something else. The `IEnumerable` that `Distinct` and `Except` return are often enough.

Comment: @JulianR: We do that so that it calculated instantaneously and not deferrred/lazy loaded in LINQ.

Answer (score 5):

First it should be

```
int[] array1 = new int[]{1,2,3,3,4,5};
```

To delete all duplicate entries do this

```
using System.Linq;

var result = array1.Distinct().ToArray();
```

To see elements which are in array1 and not in array3

```
var result = array1.Except(array3).ToArray();
```

To see elements which are in array3 and not in array1

```
var result = array3.Except(array1).ToArray();
```

[image]